# Reading cells from Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I'm having some troubles while reading from an exel in c#. 
 I have this code which i read every cell from A to X.

```
            int i = 1;
            int number;
            System.Array myvalues; string[] strArray;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "X" + i.ToString());
            while(range.Count!=0)
            {
                    i++;
                    range = worksheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "X" + i.ToString());
                    myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
                    strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
                    number = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[0]);
            }
```

My question is: How could i read next 4 * "number" rows in excel based on "number" value ?

For example:

```
         A B C D E F G H I J
         a a a a a 1 a a a a
```

F's cell value is 1 so i would like to read ( G H I J)
If F's cell value is 2 the i would like to read ( G H I J K L M N)

```
         A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
         a a a a a 2 a a a a a a a a
```

F's cell value 3 :

```
        A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R
        a a a a a 3 a a a a a a a a a a a a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
int i = 1;
do
{

   i++;
   var range = worksheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "X" + i.ToString());
   if (range.Count != 0) 
   {
      var myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
      var strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
      var number = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[0]);
      MyMethodReadRage(worksheet, number);
   }

} while(range.Count!=0);
```

method for read range:

```
void MyMethodReadRage(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet, int numberRows)
{
   var range = worksheet.get_Range("A" + numberRows, "X" + (numberRows + 4));
   /*code*/
}
```

**EDIT**

Reads the value of the column "F", multiplicas the value by 4 and add the amount of previous columns (up to "F"). You then use this (this unproven) function to get the letter.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4303
    /// </summary>
    private string ColumnLetter(int ColumnNumber)
    {
        if (ColumnNumber > 26)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{1}", (char)(Convert.ToInt32((ColumnNumber - 1) / 26) + 64), (char)(((ColumnNumber - 1) % 26) + 65));
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format("{0}", (char)(ColumnNumber + 64));
        }
    }
```

**EDIT II**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplicationExcelCeldas
{
    class Program
    { 
        private const int NumberPositionColumnF = 6;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet();

            var i = 0;
            var test = new TestExcel();
            do
            {
                i++;
                var rangeF = worksheet.get_Range(string.Format("F{0}" , i));
                if (rangeF.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                var values = test.GetCellsStringArray(rangeF);
                if (values.Count() > 0) 
                {
                    int number = 0;
                    if (int.TryParse(values[0], out number))
                    {
                        var rangeAll = worksheet.get_Range(
                            string.Format("A{0}" , i), 
                            string.Format("{0}{1}", test.ColumnLetter(Program.NumberPositionColumnF + (number * 4)), i));


                        /*
                         your code for work with rangeAll
                        */
                    }
                }

            } while (true);
        }
    }

    class TestExcel
    {
        internal string[] GetCellsStringArray(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range)
        {
            var myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
            return this.ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
        }

        internal string[] ConvertToStringArray(System.Array values)
        {
            string[] theArray = new string[values.Length];
            for (int i = 1; i <= values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (values.GetValue(1, i) == null)
                    theArray[i - 1] = "";
                else
                    theArray[i - 1] = (string)values.GetValue(1, i).ToString();
            }
            return theArray;
        }

        internal string ColumnLetter(int columnNumber)
        {
            if (columnNumber > 26)
            {
                return string.Format("{0}{1}", (char)(Convert.ToInt32((columnNumber - 1) / 26) + 64), (char)(((columnNumber - 1) % 26) + 65));
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Format("{0}", (char)(columnNumber + 64));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if the cell is "X" . I just know that the "number" is saved in "W" cell. I might have blocks of 4 , i mean ( 4*4*4)

Comment: could you put an example of excel and which would be the desired result?

Comment: then would be 4 columns, instead of 4 rows more. ok?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you perform row by row reading. May be it's better to read a range of 4 rows and then parse two dimensional array of values?

Take a look at this article: [Faster MS Excel Reading using Office Interop Assemblies](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9992/Faster-MS-Excel-Reading-using-Office-Interop-Assem)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i just created this code, it goes thru all rows from first column you can just change it as you want (latest Microsoft Lib interop DLL .NET native lib) it works just fine hope it helps you out

```
        int sheetIndex = 1; //PLEASE NOTE THIS LIB WORKS WITH NON-ZERO BASED INDEX
        string excelFilePath = "your_path/your_excel_file.xls";
        List<string> yourList = new List<string>();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);            
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[sheetIndex];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rangeSelection = worksheet.Columns[1];

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in rangeSelection.Rows)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)row.Cells[1, 1];
            if (cell.Value2 != null)
                list.Add(cell.Value2.ToString());
        }
```